# How do I get rid of this shading pattern?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

The artifacts appear when I increase the metallic factor in the bsdf shading node. Smooth shading is on, normals are correct, and I'm pretty sure there aren't any duplicate faces. I got the material from the blender market(free) and I tried to simply change the metallic value on the bsdf.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The screenshot a node group named “alternating color” with an off-screen vector plugging into it. Bluntly, even with how almost ridiculous little information that gives on the shader tree, I’m sure it’s the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome! There is something wrong, maybe clipping, with the calculation you feed into the Height of the 2nd bump node. double check the "Knitter Shape" calculation.

Comment: After messing around with other files, it seems that the edges appear with procedural materials in general when the metallic factor increases and its just prominent in this file. I've messed with the nodes in this file including the ones feeding into the second bump map and nothing seems to cause it except the metallic factor. Is this just something I'd have to just work around?

Comment: The answer is very simple. Your quad polygons are not planar. The renderer only sees triangles, not quads, so the ones that face upwards or lit brightly, and the ones that face downwards or lit dimly.

Comment: You can kinda circumvent it with a bit of tweaking though. I have to say the material is a bit suprising. Usually physically speaking a surface is either metallic (1) or not (0), here it's set to 0.6 or so which is weird. Also the roughness is set to 0 which makes it extremely reflective, thus making it obvious your faces are not planar since light is reflected in its entirety relatively to the surface normal. Try setting it to a higher value (0.4 or so)

Comment: I think what the author of the material wanted to do is use the Sheen factor instead of the material. You can manually entrer a value higher than 1 to get a more noticeable effect. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HqIH.png

Comment: @Gorgious the non planar quads is true but im not sure if thats the reason since the smoothness works with another material, just not with the OP's customized shader. i think its something with the bump map.

Comment: After looking again, its definitely the bump map. When I remove the second bump node, the shading is smooth. Im having a hard time finding the root cause. I'm gonna continue messing with the related nodes though.

Comment: Ok I found a good work-around. I increased the roughness to about 3.5. I disconnected the bump node from the Principled bsdf.(The translucent bdsf still has the issue but its hard to notice.) I then connected the bump map to the metallic factor with a  ColorRamp and math-multiply node in between. And now the individual stands are shiny like I wanted without the artifacts being noticable.